# From nilpotent matrix to Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

Let's say I have a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb F)$, and it's given that $A$ is a nilpotent matrix. How Can I find a Jordan matrix that is similar to $A$?

because $A$ is nilpotent, I can find a basis $B$ s.t. $A$ represented by the basis $B$ is a Jordan matrix with eigenvalue $0$. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: what's $\mathbb F$ ?

Comment: @GCab Let's say it's $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're not required to find the basis $B$, then our job is a lot easier.

Note that $J$ is the Jordan form corresponding to $A$, then $\operatorname{rank}(A^k) = \operatorname{rank}(J^k)$.  Moreover, for $k = 1,2,\dots,n$, $\operatorname{rank}(J^{k-1}) - \operatorname{rank}(J^k)$ is the number of Jordan blocks in $J$ with size at least $k$.  Finally, note that $A$ is nilpotent, which means that $0$ is its only eigenvalue, which means that we only need to worry about blocks for the eigenvalue $0$.

Putting all this together, it suffices to determine $\operatorname{rank}(A^k)$ for all $k \leq m$, where $m$ is the first integer such that $A^m = 0$.

This process is described in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*.

Comment: @z00x It would be nice if you could explain why neither of the answers given are sufficient to you.  As of now, it's not clear what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We consider an explicit example in dimension $7$; let (in the Maple format)

$A= Matrix(7, 7, {(1, 1) = -1, (1, 2) = 1, (1, 3) = 3, (1, 4) = 7, (1, 5) = -3, (1, 6) = 5, (1, 7) = -1, (2, 1) = -3, (2, 2) = 2, (2, 3) = 1, (2, 4) = 1, (2, 5) = 2, (2, 6) = -7, (2, 7) = 0, (3, 1) = 0, (3, 2) = -1, (3, 3) = -1, (3, 4) = -2, (3, 5) = 0, (3, 6) = -1, (3, 7) = 0, (4, 1) = 1, (4, 2) = 0, (4, 3) = 1, (4, 4) = 3, (4, 5) = -2, (4, 6) = 5, (4, 7) = 0, (5, 1) = 2, (5, 2) = -1, (5, 3) = -1, (5, 4) = -1, (5, 5) = -1, (5, 6) = 3, (5, 7) = 1, (6, 1) = 0, (6, 2) = 0, (6, 3) = -1, (6, 4) = -2, (6, 5) = 1, (6, 6) = -3, (6, 7) = 1, (7, 1) = 1, (7, 2) = -1, (7, 3) = -2, (7, 4) = -4, (7, 5) = 1, (7, 6) = -2, (7, 7) = 1})$

We obtain $dim(\ker(A))=3,dim(\ker(A^2))=6,dim(\ker(A^3))=7$.

Step 1. We seek $7-6=1$ linearly independent (L.I.) vectors in $\ker(A^3)\setminus\ker(A^2)$: $u=[4,-33,0,16,22,1,11]^T$. $Au\in\ker(A^2)\setminus\ker(A),A^2u\in\ker(A)$. We put (in reverse order) $e_1=A^2u,e_2=Au,e_3=u$.

Step 2. It remains to obtain $6-3-1=2$ vectors L.I. (with $e_2$) in $\ker(A^2)\setminus\ker(A)$: 
$v=[3,-33,0,16,22,1,11]^T,w=[2,-27,0,13,18,1,9]^T$. $Av\in\ker(A)$; in reverse order, $e_4=Av,e_5=v$. $Aw\in\ker(A)$; in reverse order, $e_6=Aw,e_7=w$.

It adds up! Let $Q=[e_1,\cdots,e_7]$. Then $Q^{-1}AQ=diag(J_3,J_2,J_2)$ where $J_k$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $k$.

Remark. This method is valid for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of any matrix $A$: replace $\ker(A^k)$ with $\ker((A-\lambda I)^k)$.